# Livewire: binding a model, can all fields be seen on the front?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In V2, if I bind a model to a public property, can then someone obtain model info from the front such as id, password etc?

```php
class UserComponent extends Component {

    public User $user;
    
    // ...
```

I notice the new `$rules` property protects what can be written.

Comment: Check the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json. You can use `protected $hidden = ['id', 'password'];` in the `User.php` model, and those field won't be shown if the model is converted to an Array or JSON.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks, I knew it was there, just tldr. Would still like to know if it was technically possible.

Comment: No problem :) I _think_ that would work, but at the same time I've never used Laravel Livewire, so I can't say for sure this satisfies your requirements.